# Connection to Hbase in Azure HDInsight with Simba ODBC driver

Tags: azure, odbc, hbase, azure-hdinsight

I am running HBase in Azure HDInsight and can access HBase Rest API in my browser through https://my_claster_name.azurehdinsight.net/hbaserest. Trying to configure Simba HBase ODBC driver to connect to the HBase installation I always get

Failure: [Simba][HBase] (20) Error with HTTP API: Couldn't connect to server

For host I tried my_claster_name.azurehdinsight.net/hbaserest and just my_claster_name.azurehdinsight.net I also tried 8080 and 80 for ports. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From the doucument of Simba, it needs you to provide `http://host:port` of the rest server. However, for hdinsight clusters, it is https and all requests need to go through gateway and reroute to any one of the rest servers inside the cluster.

One way to resolve this is to create a VNET, and include your HBase cluster and your own machine in it. In this way you do not need to access gateway and can directly hit any rest server you want. the url is `http://workernode{N}:8090`. N is depend on how many workernodes you have.